# How to route Apache Camel to an in-memory ActiveMQ JMS queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

TLDR: I want to know how to connect to an in-memory JMS queue created with spring boot java and default configuration, using the apache camel routing.
Currently I try to connect but it keeps showing the error:

> Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

I tried editing the properties to modify the configuration, and the routing, by adding parameters but I had no success. Any help is appreciated. I leave the whole code below for those who want details.

MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JmsConfiguration.java:

```java
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfiguration {

@Autowired
private BeanFactory springContextBeanFactory;

@Bean
public Queue queue(){
    return new ActiveMQQueue("inmemory.queue");
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException {
    return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
}

}
```

Producer.java

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.jms.Queue;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("publish")
public class Producer {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Queue queue;

    @GetMapping("/{message}")
    public String publishString(@PathVariable("message") final String message){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message);
        return "published succesfully";
    }
}
```

Consumer.java

```java
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "inmemory.queue")
    public void listener(String message){
        System.out.println("Receiveage: -> " +message);
    }
}
```

application-default.yml

```
spring:    
  activemq:
    in-memory: true
    pool:
      enabled: false
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then configured the Apache Camel route:

```java
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class FooRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
// sender
    from("foo-bar")
    .to("activemq:queue:inmemory.queue");
// receiver
    from("activemq:queue:inmemory.queue")
    .to("bar-foo");
    }
}
```

Log from server:

```
2018-12-30 15:12:04,549 INFO  [main] org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService : Using Persistence Adapter: MemoryPersistenceAdapter
2018-12-30 15:12:04,624 INFO  [JMX connector] org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext : JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
2018-12-30 15:12:04,757 INFO  [main] org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService : Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:hostname-12345-1234567890123-0:1) is starting
2018-12-30 15:12:04,770 INFO  [main] org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService : Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:hostname-12345-1234567890123-0:1) started
2018-12-30 15:12:04,770 INFO  [main] org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService : For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
2018-12-30 15:12:04,995 INFO  [main] org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector : Connector vm://localhost started
2018-12-30 16:01:49,872 WARN  [ActiveMQ Task-1] org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport : Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece is the configuration of the Camel ActiveMQComponent that is referenced in your JMS route endpoints as `activemq:`

Notice the `@Qualifier` annotation to make sure the bean name matches the name in your JMS route endpoints.

You inject the ConnectionFactory into the component. That way the component gets the broker URL etc.

Example for such a configuration with transacted message consumption:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("activemq")
ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMQComponent.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    activeMQComponent.transacted = true;
    activeMQComponent.lazyCreateTransactionManager = false;
    activeMQComponent.cacheLevelName = 'CACHE_CONSUMER';
    activeMQComponent.concurrentConsumers = 5;
    return activeMQComponent;
}
```